# Centos - /var/log/secure records nothing

Tags: centos, permissions, log-files

I have accidentally remove /var/log/secure, I try to recreate it but it still stays blank after several connections.

On a server where everything works, with ls -l I have:

```
-rw-------. root:root /var/log/secure
```

and on a server where it does not work, with ls -l I have:

```
-rw------- root:root /var/log/secure
```

The only difference is in the rights with the "."  at the end of the line, that's missing on the server where it does not work.

Any idea ?

Comment: Did you restart the `rsyslog` service?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So the issue is your syslog process still has the deleted file open. You need to restart your syslog process. By default that is rsyslog in centos

```
 service rsyslog restart
```

I'm sure you can see it opened as deleted also if you try something like

```
 lsof | grep '/var/log/secure'
```

That will give you the pid/process name of what is holding it open. For example

```
[root@nagios01-east.domain.com ~]#  lsof | grep '/var/log/secure'
rsyslogd    977       root    5w      REG              253,0   585555    2756243 /var/log/secure
```

So the rsyslogd process is holding it open

```
[root@nagios01-east.domain.com ~]# ps aux | grep 977
root       977  0.0  0.0 249856  5916 ?        Sl    2014   8:25 /sbin/rsyslogd -i /var/run/syslogd.pid -
```

Comment: Even better would be to **not** start by restarting rsyslog! Since the file is being kept open, /var/log/secure is not deleted yet and you can easily recover that file. Run the lsof command and then use the open file descriptor to recover the accidentally deleted file. Using the PID number (977) and file-descriptor number (5) from your example: `cp /proc/977/fd/5 /var/log/secure.bak`